# Elements not going where they should in fragment XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/movies_fragment_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MoviesFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMovies"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:layout_weight="100"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLoadData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load api data"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

onCreate from MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.movies_fragment_ll, new MoviesFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the code is meant to display what's on the left, but what it's actually displaying is different. I've tried to play around with the XML and java but it keeps doing that. In some instances, depending on how I arrange the ListView and Button on the screen, I sometimes get two Buttons instead of one.

Why?

To clear the confusion.
Data is being added to the ListView.
Data is added on button click.

But before the button is clicked, and data is added to the ListView.

How do I make the ListView height finish just where the button starts at the bottom. To make the layout look like the one in the XML preview.

Comment: where is your list view adapter initialization????

Comment: @Roy https://gist.github.com/sebi1995/2bc5d801ed9817efd1b19dae9e947626

Comment: Plz check my answer @SebastianZdroana

Comment: @Roy Unless you add some data to the list in MoviesFragment.java, list view will not be inflated. Use Adapter to provide data to the view.

Comment: That is the reason i asked him to post his adapter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android preview shows a list with child.But at runtime you are not adding any element in the list view , so list view is empty . in that case your button moves to up.

if you want your button to stick in bottom use Relative layout.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/movies_fragment_ll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MoviesFragment">


  <Button
    android:id="@+id/bLoadData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Load api data"
    />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvMovies"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#efefef"
    android:layout_above="@id/bLoadData"
    android:layout_weight="100"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but how do i make the listview height finish just on top of the button? in the RelativeLayout, just like in the emulator (in the screenshot)

Comment: add data in your list view adapter . I think your ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> posters is empty so your list is empty. if posters has some elements than you will achieve what you want.

Comment: add     alignParentBottom="true"     property to Button as per need.

Comment: change the android:layout_height="wrap_content" to fill_parent for listview

Answer (score 0):

the list wont be visible if you dont have any data in that list. So that why the button will be shown on the top because listview's height will be 0.

Set some data to the list, and use relative layout to manage the location of the button at bottom

Answer (score 0):

Well change it like This,and Please add some data to adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/movies_fragment_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MoviesFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMovies"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#efefef"
        android:layout_weight="100"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLoadData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Load api data"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```